# Return from a namespace function called from a qt class back into the class

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

I have a `CadThread` class that is suppose to make my geometry. This class has a public slot `void MakeMesh(cadData aCadData)` that calls one of the namespace functions depending on the model type (from `aCadData`) (defined in MakeMeshStructure.hh):

```
namespace MeshStructure1 {
void MakeMeshStructure  (//parameters... );
}
namespace MeshStructure2 {
void MakeMeshStructure  (//parameters... );
}
namespace MeshStructure3 {
void MakeMeshStructure  (//parameters...
```

This functions are generating shapes inside for example MakeMeshStructure3.cc. I would like to return this shapes back to CadThread class that called them in a slot like:

```
void Add_Shape(TopoDS_Shape& shape, Quantity_NameOfColor colorName);
```

so I can emit the shape from this slot (or maybe just member function) back to the main thread when MakeMeshStructure3 produces a shape (one run of `MakeMeshStructure3` produces several shapes).

Can anyone give me an example of how this is done right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your code (a less abstract example could have been helpful), but this sounds to me like a good place to use polymorphism instead of namespaces. Create a base `MeshStructure` class, and have all other structures subclass it. Make the shapes polymorphic as well, so every mesh structure produces a different shape, but they all could be treated by a `Shape` pointer or reference.

Answer (score 0):

If the code in `MakeMeshStructure#.cc` is using Qt then I don't see what your problem is: just emit a signal there, even from a temporary QObject, and be done with it.

If the meshmaker code is *not* using Qt, or you want to keep Qt dependencies minimal, then simply have the code generate the mesh on the heap and pass it to a function invoked by a function pointer. That function can be external to the meshmaker and will either emit a signal on an instance of QObject that it knows about, or will post an event to the cad thread.